# JAX with JIT and custom differentiation

Tags: python, jax, numpyro

I am working with JAX through numpyro. Specially, I want to use a B-spline function (e.g. implemented in `scipy.interpolate.BSpline`) to transform different points into a spline where the input depends on some of the parameters in the model. Thus, I need to be able to differentiate the B-spline in JAX (only in the input argument and not in the knots or the integer order (of course!)).

I can easily use `jax.custom_vjp` but not when JIT is used as it is in numpyro. I looked at the following:

1. https://github.com/google/jax/issues/1142
2. https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Custom_derivative_rules_for_Python_code.html

and it seems like the best hope is to use a callback. **Though, I cannot figure out entirely how that would work.**
At https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.experimental.host_callback.html#using-call-to-call-a-jax-function-on-another-device-with-reverse-mode-autodiff-support

the TensorFlow example with reverse mode autodiff seem not to use JIT.

#### The example

Here is Python code that works without JIT (see the `b_spline_basis()` function):

```py
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
import numpy as np
from numpy import typing as npt
from functools import partial
import jax

doubleArray = npt.NDArray[np.double]

# see
#   https://stackoverflow.com/q/74699053/5861244
#   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Derivative_expressions
def _b_spline_deriv_inner(spline: BSpline, deriv_basis: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:  # type: ignore[no-any-unimported]
    out = np.zeros((deriv_basis.shape[0], deriv_basis.shape[1] - 1))

    for col_index in range(out.shape[1] - 1):
        scale = spline.t[col_index + spline.k + 1] - spline.t[col_index + 1]
        if scale != 0:
            out[:, col_index] = -deriv_basis[:, col_index + 1] / scale

    for col_index in range(1, out.shape[1]):
        scale = spline.t[col_index + spline.k] - spline.t[col_index]
        if scale != 0:
            out[:, col_index] += deriv_basis[:, col_index] / scale

    return float(spline.k) * out


def _b_spline_eval(spline: BSpline, x: doubleArray, deriv: int) -> doubleArray:  # type: ignore[no-any-unimported]
    if deriv == 0:
        return spline.design_matrix(x=x, t=spline.t, k=spline.k).todense()
    elif spline.k <= 0:
        return np.zeros((x.shape[0], spline.t.shape[0] - spline.k - 1))

    return _b_spline_deriv_inner(
        spline=spline,
        deriv_basis=_b_spline_eval(
            BSpline(t=spline.t, k=spline.k - 1, c=np.zeros(spline.c.shape[0] + 1)), x=x, deriv=deriv - 1
        ),
    )


@partial(jax.custom_vjp, nondiff_argnums=(0, 1, 2))
def b_spline_basis(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:
    return _b_spline_eval(spline=BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros((order + knots.shape[0] - 1))), x=x, deriv=deriv)[
        :, 1:
    ]


def b_spline_basis_fwd(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> tuple[doubleArray, doubleArray]:
    spline = BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros(order + knots.shape[0] - 1))
    return (
        _b_spline_eval(spline=spline, x=x, deriv=deriv)[:, 1:],
        _b_spline_eval(spline=spline, x=x, deriv=deriv + 1)[:, 1:],
    )


def b_spline_basis_bwd(
    knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, partials: doubleArray, grad: doubleArray
) -> tuple[doubleArray]:
    return (jax.numpy.sum(partials * grad, axis=1),)


b_spline_basis.defvjp(b_spline_basis_fwd, b_spline_basis_bwd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests

    knots = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    x = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])
    order = 3

    def test_jax(basis: doubleArray, partials: doubleArray, deriv: int) -> None:
        weights = jax.numpy.arange(1, basis.shape[1] + 1)

        def test_func(x: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:
            return jax.numpy.sum(jax.numpy.dot(b_spline_basis(knots=knots, order=order, deriv=deriv, x=x), weights))  # type: ignore[no-any-return]

        assert np.allclose(test_func(x), np.sum(np.dot(basis, weights)))
        assert np.allclose(jax.grad(test_func)(x), np.dot(partials, weights))

    deriv0 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                0.684,
                0.166666666666667,
                0.00133333333333333,
                0.096,
                0.444444444444444,
                0.0355555555555555,
                0.004,
                0.351851851851852,
                0.312148148148148,
                0,
                0.037037037037037,
                0.650962962962963,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )

    deriv1 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                2.52,
                -1,
                -0.04,
                1.68,
                -0.666666666666667,
                -0.666666666666667,
                0.12,
                1.22222222222222,
                -2.29777777777778,
                0,
                0.444444444444444,
                3.00444444444444,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv0, deriv1, deriv=0)

    deriv2 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                -69.6,
                4,
                0.8,
                9.6,
                -5.33333333333333,
                5.33333333333333,
                2.4,
                -2.22222222222222,
                -15.3777777777778,
                0,
                3.55555555555556,
                9.24444444444445,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv1, deriv2, deriv=1)

    deriv3 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                504,
                -8,
                -8,
                -144,
                26.6666666666667,
                26.6666666666667,
                24,
                -32.8888888888889,
                -32.8888888888889,
                0,
                14.2222222222222,
                14.2222222222222,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv2, deriv3, deriv=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is probably using a combination of `custom_jvp` and [`jax.pure_callback`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.pure_callback.html).

Unfortunately, `pure_callback` is relatively new and does not have great documentation yet, but you can find examples of its use in the JAX user forums (for example [here](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/13277#discussioncomment-4161717)).

Copied here for posterity, this is an example of computing the sine and cosine via numpy callbacks in jit-compatible code with custom JVP rules for autodiff.

```py
import jax
import numpy as np
jax.config.update('jax_enable_x64', True)

@jax.custom_jvp
def np_sin(x):
  # Compute the sine by calling-back to np.sin on the host.
  return jax.pure_callback(np.sin, jax.ShapeDtypeStruct(np.shape(x), np.float64), x)

@np_sin.defjvp
def _np_sin_jvp(primals, tangents):
  x, = primals
  dx, = tangents
  return np_sin(x), np_cos(x) * dx  #d sin(x) = cos(x) dx

@jax.custom_jvp
def np_cos(x):
  # Compute the cosine by calling-back to np.cos on the host.
  return jax.pure_callback(np.cos, jax.ShapeDtypeStruct(np.shape(x), np.float64), x)

@np_cos.defjvp
def _np_cos_jvp(primals, tangents):
  x, = primals
  dx, = tangents
  return np_cos(x), -np_sin(x) * dx  # d cos(x) = -sin(x) dx


print(np_sin(1.0))
# 0.8414709848078965
print(np_cos(1.0))
# 0.5403023058681398
print(jax.jit(jax.grad(np_sin))(1.0))
# 0.5403023058681398
```

Note that since `pure_callback` operates by sending data back to the host, it will generally have a lot of overhead on accelerators like GPU and TPU, although in a single-CPU setting this kind of approach can perform well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to the answer provided by [jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74721644/5861244) (the accepted and true answer). In the concrete example, the `b_spline_basis()` function and the `_fwd` and `_bwd` functions can be changed to

```py
@partial(jax.custom_vjp, nondiff_argnums=(0, 1, 2))
def b_spline_basis(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:
    return jax.pure_callback(
        lambda x: _b_spline_eval(
            spline=BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros((order + knots.shape[0] - 1))), x=x, deriv=deriv
        )[:, 1:],
        jax.ShapeDtypeStruct((x.shape[0], knots.shape[0] - order - 2), np.float64),
        x,
    )


def b_spline_basis_fwd(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> tuple[doubleArray, doubleArray]:
    spline = BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros(order + knots.shape[0] - 1))
    return (
        b_spline_basis(knots=knots, order=order, deriv=deriv, x=x),
        jax.pure_callback(
            lambda x: _b_spline_eval(spline=spline, x=x, deriv=deriv + 1)[:, 1:],
            jax.ShapeDtypeStruct((x.shape[0], knots.shape[0] - order - 2), np.float64),
            x=x,
        ),
    )


def b_spline_basis_bwd(
    knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, partials: doubleArray, grad: doubleArray
) -> tuple[doubleArray]:
    return (jax.numpy.sum(partials * grad, axis=1),)
```

then the test passes even after

```py
assert np.allclose(test_func(x), np.sum(np.dot(basis, weights)))
assert np.allclose(jax.grad(test_func)(x), np.dot(partials, weights))
```

was changed to

```py
assert np.allclose(jax.jit(test_func)(x), np.sum(np.dot(basis, weights)))
assert np.allclose(jax.jit(jax.grad(test_func))(x), np.dot(partials, weights))
```

Here is the complete code for the record:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline
import numpy as np
from numpy import typing as npt
from functools import partial
import jax

jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)


doubleArray = npt.NDArray[np.double]

# see
#   https://stackoverflow.com/q/74699053/5861244
#   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Derivative_expressions
def _b_spline_deriv_inner(spline: BSpline, deriv_basis: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:  # type: ignore[no-any-unimported]
    out = np.zeros((deriv_basis.shape[0], deriv_basis.shape[1] - 1))

    for col_index in range(out.shape[1] - 1):
        scale = spline.t[col_index + spline.k + 1] - spline.t[col_index + 1]
        if scale != 0:
            out[:, col_index] = -deriv_basis[:, col_index + 1] / scale

    for col_index in range(1, out.shape[1]):
        scale = spline.t[col_index + spline.k] - spline.t[col_index]
        if scale != 0:
            out[:, col_index] += deriv_basis[:, col_index] / scale

    return float(spline.k) * out


def _b_spline_eval(spline: BSpline, x: doubleArray, deriv: int) -> doubleArray:  # type: ignore[no-any-unimported]
    if deriv == 0:
        return spline.design_matrix(x=x, t=spline.t, k=spline.k).todense()
    elif spline.k <= 0:
        return np.zeros((x.shape[0], spline.t.shape[0] - spline.k - 1))

    return _b_spline_deriv_inner(
        spline=spline,
        deriv_basis=_b_spline_eval(
            BSpline(t=spline.t, k=spline.k - 1, c=np.zeros(spline.c.shape[0] + 1)), x=x, deriv=deriv - 1
        ),
    )


@partial(jax.custom_vjp, nondiff_argnums=(0, 1, 2))
def b_spline_basis(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:
    return jax.pure_callback(
        lambda x: _b_spline_eval(
            spline=BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros((order + knots.shape[0] - 1))), x=x, deriv=deriv
        )[:, 1:],
        jax.ShapeDtypeStruct((x.shape[0], knots.shape[0] - order - 2), np.float64),
        x,
    )


def b_spline_basis_fwd(knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, x: doubleArray) -> tuple[doubleArray, doubleArray]:
    spline = BSpline(t=knots, k=order, c=np.zeros(order + knots.shape[0] - 1))
    return (
        b_spline_basis(knots=knots, order=order, deriv=deriv, x=x),
        jax.pure_callback(
            lambda x: _b_spline_eval(spline=spline, x=x, deriv=deriv + 1)[:, 1:],
            jax.ShapeDtypeStruct((x.shape[0], knots.shape[0] - order - 2), np.float64),
            x=x,
        ),
    )


def b_spline_basis_bwd(
    knots: doubleArray, order: int, deriv: int, partials: doubleArray, grad: doubleArray
) -> tuple[doubleArray]:
    return (jax.numpy.sum(partials * grad, axis=1),)


b_spline_basis.defvjp(b_spline_basis_fwd, b_spline_basis_bwd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests

    knots = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    x = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])
    order = 3

    def test_jax(basis: doubleArray, partials: doubleArray, deriv: int) -> None:
        weights = jax.numpy.arange(1, basis.shape[1] + 1)

        def test_func(x: doubleArray) -> doubleArray:
            return jax.numpy.sum(jax.numpy.dot(b_spline_basis(knots=knots, order=order, deriv=deriv, x=x), weights))  # type: ignore[no-any-return]

        assert np.allclose(jax.jit(test_func)(x), np.sum(np.dot(basis, weights)))
        assert np.allclose(jax.jit(jax.grad(test_func))(x), np.dot(partials, weights))

    deriv0 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                0.684,
                0.166666666666667,
                0.00133333333333333,
                0.096,
                0.444444444444444,
                0.0355555555555555,
                0.004,
                0.351851851851852,
                0.312148148148148,
                0,
                0.037037037037037,
                0.650962962962963,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )

    deriv1 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                2.52,
                -1,
                -0.04,
                1.68,
                -0.666666666666667,
                -0.666666666666667,
                0.12,
                1.22222222222222,
                -2.29777777777778,
                0,
                0.444444444444444,
                3.00444444444444,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv0, deriv1, deriv=0)

    deriv2 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                -69.6,
                4,
                0.8,
                9.6,
                -5.33333333333333,
                5.33333333333333,
                2.4,
                -2.22222222222222,
                -15.3777777777778,
                0,
                3.55555555555556,
                9.24444444444445,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv1, deriv2, deriv=1)

    deriv3 = np.transpose(
        np.array(
            [
                504,
                -8,
                -8,
                -144,
                26.6666666666667,
                26.6666666666667,
                24,
                -32.8888888888889,
                -32.8888888888889,
                0,
                14.2222222222222,
                14.2222222222222,
            ]
        ).reshape(-1, 3)
    )
    test_jax(deriv2, deriv3, deriv=2)
```